# My image wont display on my landing page rather, it will show the name of the image

Tags: php, session

the code below is my form action, but when there is a successfully login, all data display on my landing page but it wont display the image rather it will display the the name of the image.

```
<?php 
// Connect to the database
require('config.php'); 
// Set username and password variables for this script
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]); 
// Make sure the username and password match, selecting all the client's
// data from the database if it does. Store the data into $clientdata
$clientdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$user' and password='$pass'")
 or die (mysql_error());
// Put the $clientdata query into an array we can work with
$data = mysql_fetch_array($clientdata, MYSQL_ASSOC);
// If the username and password matched, we should have one entry in our
// $clientdata array. If not, we should have 0. So, we can use a simple
// if/else statement
if(mysql_num_rows($clientdata) == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $user;
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $data['firstname'];
   $_SESSION['lastname'] = $data['lastname'];
    $_SESSION['address'] = $data['address'];
 $_SESSION['nationality'] = $data['nationality'];
   $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
  $_SESSION['photo']=$data['photo'];
?>
<?php
          }else{echo "Click Login to try again or Register for an account. 
          Thank You";}
        ?>
```

## I creat a html table where the image will be placed inside and the text field of the image upload is photo and the image  directory is upload.

```
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#999999">Passport</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><p><?php echo "" . $_SESSION['photo'] . ""; ?></p></tr>
```

Comment: What is the code that generates the HTML to show the photo? What is the an example value of $data['photo'] ?

Comment: To get the attention of the correct parties, please [edit] the question and add the applicable language tags. To increase the chances of getting an answer that solves your problem, add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Ryan Mcdonough,  $_SESSION['Photo']=$data['photo'] is inside my form action, and on my landing page, i have <?php echo "" . $_SESSION['photo'] . ""; ?>, but it only display the image name not the picture itself, i want the image to be display and the image is already stored in my image directory which the name is upload

Comment: Well what is the content of $data['photo']; If it's the file location you'll need to do <img src=" <?php echo "" . $_SESSION['photo'] . ""; ?>" > or if it's bytes then you'll need to convert the bytes to image. If it's just the name of the file then you are retrieving the incorrect field from the database.

Comment: @Ryan .sorry for borthering you! what do you mean bu content  of $data['photo'], well if i understand you very well, what i uploaded was image

Comment: As in what are you setting $data['photo'] to be? Is it the photos location or is it the image bytes?

Answer (score 0):

You say it prints out the name of the image and the image is stored in your image directory. I'm guessing that means `$_SESSION[ 'photo' ]` contains the path to the image file. In that case you need to wrap it in HTML properly.

`<img src="<?php echo $_SESSION[ 'photo' ] ?>" />`

Or perhaps your uploaded images are in an images folder and you only store the actual file name in `$_SESSION[ 'photo' ]`, then do this instead.

`<img src="/your-images-folder/<?php echo $_SESSION[ 'photo' ] ?>" />`

If the images are stored outside of your web root, then you'll need to either copy them in to your web root, or you'll need to set up a PHP script to receive unhandled image requests and pull in the files from your uploaded images folder that way.

You can do this by putting a URL rewrite rule into your server config (Apache's .conf file for example), so that any requests to, say, `/uploaded-images/*` where the image file doesn't actually exist, get rewritten to your PHP script. Your PHP script can then find the correct image in the uploads folder and using the `header()` and `file_get_contents()` functions, display it back to the user with the correct mime type.

Comment: now the image is display but each user has different image but what is only one particular image is displaying on the users account page but their various details displays properly.<?php 
  if ($rows['photo']) { 
    $row = $rows['photo'];
    $imagepath = "<img width'60' height='70' src='upload/$row' >"; 
      
echo $imagepath ; 
 }
 else {
echo "<img width'60' height='70' src='upload/' >" ;
} 

  ?>